# Android media player doesn't work for the second time

Tags: android

With this piece of code I was able to run the song in the background clicking the 'yes' button and stop it with 'no', but it works only once. If I click the yes button again (second time) the application stops. So need a help, I want my my activity to run and stop the music with these Alert dialog's buttons accordngly every time they're clicked.

```
public class Music extends Activity {

final Context context = this;
MediaPlayer song;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Turn ON the music?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    song.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    try {
                        song = MediaPlayer.create(Music.this, R.raw.fing);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    try {
                        song.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    song.start();
                }


               // dialog.cancel();
            }


                )


                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog,int id){
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        if(song!=null && song.isPlaying()){
                            song.stop();
                            dialog.cancel();

                        }
                    }} );

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();}}
```

Comment: try assign and set audio `MediaPlayer song` in the `onCreate`, in `PositiveButton` just `song.start();`

Comment: @Waki I tried it at first, It works but only once; If I click 'yes'_first time_ the song plays and if I click 'no'_first time_ it stops and when I click 'yes' again _second time_ the application stops. So I used  try/catch but it didn't worked as well.

Comment: you not understand me, `setAudioStreamType`, `MediaPlayer.create` and `prepare` also put in `onCreate`, in `PositiveButton` `onClick` just `song.start();`

Comment: That didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

All the initialisation of your media player (such as create, setAudioStreamType, prepare) instance you can put in onCreate method not in onClick of dialog. And in onClick just call stop and play methods.

Like this

```
public class Music extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;
    MediaPlayer song;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    song.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        try {
                            song = MediaPlayer.create(Music.this, R.raw.fing);
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (SecurityException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        try {
                            song.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Turn ON the music?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    song.start();
                }


               // dialog.cancel();
            }


                )


                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog,int id){
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        if(song!=null && song.isPlaying()){
                            song.stop();
                            dialog.cancel();

                        }
                    }} );

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't mind friends but none of these worked. I think I need to use thread to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
song.reset(); // this makes sure that the song object was not assigned before (it recreates the MediaPlayer) 
                    song.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    try {
                        song = MediaPlayer.create(Music.this, R.raw.fing);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    try {
                        song.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    song.start();
                }


           // dialog.cancel();
        }


            )

.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog,int id){
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    if(song!=null && song.isPlaying()){
                        song.stop();
song.release(); // This releases the song object so you can initiate another MediaPlayer object if you want.
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                }} );
```

This resets the MediaPlayer object to make sure you have a fresh one, and if the music stops playing it releases the MediaPlayer (which also releases RAM memory)

Answer (score 1):

Try to call

```
if (song !=null){
song.release()}
```

before

```
song = MediaPlayer.create(Music.this, R.raw.fing);
```

Can you show your logs?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem calling to song.start() inside the setOnPreparedListener, any call to start outside this method produces an error.